# To extract body from html text in gmail using googlescript

Tags: javascript, html, gmail-api, extract

I need to get the contents of a particular tag of the html text i recieve in my mail. The following function returns me with just the html content as a whole. So it comes as an invalid argument to append in the spread sheet.

```
function myFunction() {

  if(GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount() > 0)
  {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var mailThreads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 1);
    //Logger.log(mailThreads.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < mailThreads.length; i++) 
    {
        var mailThread = mailThreads[i];
        var messages = mailThread.getMessages()[0];
        var url = messages.getBody();//to get the html type text
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);    
        mailThread.markRead();
    }
     sheet.append([response]);
  }
 }
```

**HOW DO I GET ONLY THE REQUIRED BODY CONTENT FROM THE HTML TEXT ?**

Comment: I have written [a tiny module](https://github.com/EmilTholin/gmail-api-parse-message) for this you can check out.

Comment: @Tholle  thanks ! I tried running the code in gs.. i get the error -ReferenceError : "require" is not defined.

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe you can't use it in googlescript. You can read the code and get some inspiration on how to get the html.

Comment: @Tholle can we just use the DOM to extract data by tags?